# Reachability status message appears only once

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am popping a message alerting the user that he/she has lost WIFI/intenet connection. For that, i followed the Reachability [example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_ReachabilityAppDelegate_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Classes_ReachabilityAppDelegate_m-DontLinkElementID_4) given by apple.

I added the 2 reachability classes, Rechability.h and .m, and i added the codes given in its app delegate to mine as well (an exact replica). This works perfectly.

My problem is that, this message appears only once, i want it to be displayed when it goes to each and every view.

All codes that i am using can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_ReachabilityAppDelegate_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Classes_ReachabilityAppDelegate_m-DontLinkElementID_4). Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmm... Not sure to understand what you expect Rechability does.

This class is designed to get any change in your rechability status. When a change is detected Reachability send a notification, but if nothing changes you won't get any notification.

EDIT: to get your reachability status and to use it later you can add a BOOL (internetIsDown) to the method where you read notification from Reachability.

```
- (void)checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice {
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (internetStatus) {
        case NotReachable: {
            internetIsDown = YES;
            break;
        } case ReachableViaWiFi: {
            internetIsDown = NO;
            break;
        } case ReachableViaWWAN: {
            internetIsDown = NO;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can check for this BOOL value whenever needed and display an alert to the user.

N.B. internetIsDown should be a singleton if you want to access its value from any viewController!!!

Comment: Yes, when the internet is down it will show the message. and if the internet is down forever and if the user clicks on a different view he/she will not know that the internet is down because the message was already displayed. So i need a way where this message will appear when he/she navigates to each and every view. How can i do this ?

Comment: Ah... I see, take a look at my EDIT.

Comment: What do you mean by `internetIsDown should be a singleton` ?

Comment: I mean a global variable accessible from any class.

Answer (score 1):

You could call [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] in each view's viewDidAppear method...

But like others have mentioned, it could be kind of annoying to see the same message over and over.

Answer (score 1):

I have an application where I have tabs. The root controller registers for reachability messages. An *UIAlertView* is used to display a warning. This is shown in all parts of the application.